# WPF listview display items to columns based on height of window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have been trying to create a listview to display MySQL tables but I can't figure out, how I can make the items to be arranged to columns using xaml?

This is what i have

[image: My ListView]

And this is what i would like to make:

[image: Other program layout]

Also, when I resize the window i want the items to be arranged to new columns like this:
[image: Resize Window- rearrange the items]

This is my xaml code:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" 
          Grid.Row="1" 
          x:Name="DBTables" 
          ItemsSource="{ Binding Path=TABLENAME
                       , Source={StaticResource DBManagerResource} }" 
          MinHeight="280" 
          MinWidth="400">
      <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
              <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                           Handler="DBTableSelect_MouseDoubleClick" />
          </Style>
      </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Your example images are not available

Comment: @MightyBadaboom What do you mean by not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `WrapPanel` with `Orientation="Vertical"`, disable the vertical scrolling on the listview with `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` and configure the `ListView.ItemTemplate` in order to show the icon in front of each list entry.

```
<ListView MinHeight="280" MinWidth="400" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <!--Replace rectangle by your icon-->
                <Rectangle Width="15" Height="15" Margin="5" Fill="Red" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! You helped a lot

Comment: Didn't he just say what i've said ? :)  (he did write it up for you, i'll give him that)

Comment: @Noctis Since I already had my answer like 90% completed when the other answers appeared and I felt like mine is more complete than the others, I decided to post it anyway ;)

Comment: @grek40 no worries mate. I'm simply amused. You gave a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you're looking for a `WrapPanel` or something similar. have a look at [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans).

you might want to have a play with the style of your items so they show an icon and a text, but that shouldn't be hard to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This code will take care of items during resize. Maybe it will help you.

```
<ListView>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel 
                    Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                    ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                    MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                    ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <!-- Here you should add you item template, like image and text -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the items panel of the ListBox and disable the vertical scrollbar

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">        
     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```